# MySQL join two tables to produce column with comma separated values

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have a mysql problem, and maybe the title is a little confusing, but here goes:

I have two tables

```
    TABLE A           TABLE B
+-----+--------+   +-----+--------+
| id  | NumCol |   | id  | NumCol |
+-----+--------+   +-----+--------+
| 101 |  123   |   | 101 |        |
| 101 |  124   |   +-----+--------+  
+-----+--------+
```

Now I'd like to join these two on the id, so I get an output like this

```
+-----+--------+
| id  | NumCol |
+-----+--------+
| 101 | 123,124|
+-----+--------+
```

Anyone know of a handy way to do this?

Comment: Why `tableB` is required??

Comment: Why do you even need table B? all the data seems to come from table A.

Comment: Table B also has some different columns, that I didn't write so I wouldn't complicate things, I don't mind if you can just alter table A to get the result either!

Comment: @12344343243 is it possible that numcol from tableb has also data which sould be part of the csv?

Comment: No, that's just an empty column

Comment: @12344343243 Why you have empty columns in your table?

Comment: My mysql skills are not that great

Comment: You haven't at all described how your desired output is related to your inputs. Please do so. Please read & act on [mcve]. Please edit clarifications into your answer, not comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Try this query**

```
SELECT tb.id,GROUP_CONCAT(ta.NumCol) AS NumCol FROM tableB AS tb
JOIN tableA AS ta ON ta.id=tb.id
GROUP BY tb.id
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try:

```
SELECT tableA.id, GROUP_CONCAT(tableA.NumCol) as NumCol
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.id = tableB.id
GROUP BY tableA.id
```

Comment: You shud suggest modern explizit join Syntax not the older Version with where

Comment: yes this is right @Jens i just want to make it readable for the OP that's all